# Unordered_map having strange behavior when accessing elements

Tags: c++, unordered-map

I have an unordered map that looks like this:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, double> payments = { {"8/18", 0.0}, {"7/18", 771.98}, {"6/18", 0.0}, {"5/18", 771.98},
                                                    {"4/18", 771.98}, {"3/18", 771.98}, {"2/18", 0.0}, {"1/18", 3859.90},
                                                    {"12/17", 771.98}, {"11/17", 0.0}, {"10/17", 1543.96}, {"9/17", 771.98} };
```

When I print the second element as so:

```
for (auto it : payments)
    {
        std::cout << it.second << " ";
    }
```

I get this:

```
0 771.98 0 0 771.98 1543.96 771.98 771.98 771.98 3859.9 771.98
```

As you can see I have an extra zero and the ordering is not the same. How do I fix this?

Comment: `std::vector` is a good default for almost anything

Comment: If you need to maintain order of creation and have fast access by string then `boost::multiindex` is a way to go, but it is not too simple to use for a beginer unfortunately. Another way is to create `std::unordered_map<std::string,size_t>` with indexes to a `std::vector<double>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using an `std::unordered_map`.  That means the elements are stored in no particular order.  Your code is working "correctly".  If you want the order to be maintained then you need an array like container of a `std::pair` like a `std::vector<std::pair<std::string, double>>`.  Example:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, double>> payments = { {"8/18", 0.0}, {"7/18", 771.98}, {"6/18", 0.0}, {"5/18", 771.98},
                                                             {"4/18", 771.98}, {"3/18", 771.98}, {"2/18", 0.0}, {"1/18", 3859.90},
                                                             {"12/17", 771.98}, {"11/17", 0.0}, {"10/17", 1543.96}, {"9/17", 771.98} };

    for (auto it : payments)
    {
        std::cout << it.second << " ";
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
0 771.98 0 771.98 771.98 771.98 0 3859.9 771.98 0 1543.96 771.98
```